# I don't understand An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have issues understanding why this code doesn't work (text explanation of the problem below):

```py
import asyncio
from random import randrange

def main_function():
    n = randrange(2)
    if n:
        return 1
    else:
        return None

def backup_function():
    return 1

async def run():
    jobs1 = [main_function() for _ in range(0, 5)]
    jobs2 = [backup_function() for _ in range(0, 5)]

    _res = await asyncio.gather(*jobs1)
    if len(_res) < 5:
        _res = await asyncio.gather(*jobs2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

Ok, let's say I have an async function `run` where I have a list of jobs `jobs1` I want to get done by calling `asyncio.gather`. These jobs are simulated in my example by the function `main_function`, because, in short, the real function we are talking about here returns 'something' or None, whether it internally 'fails' or not, simulated with `return 1` or `return None`. `asyncio.gather` returns a list with the results of the executed jobs, so my understanding. I thought, that `await` now waits for all jobs to finish, so, `_res`could be an empty list or filled with a maximum of five 1s, depending on `randrange(2)` in this case, of course.

I now need to check, if all of the executions of my `jobs1` returned a 1 or if there may have been one execution, which returned `None`, so I wanted to check that with `if len(_res) < 5`, and in this case, execute another `asyncio.gather` with another `backup_function`, but this leads to an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cptsnuggles/run.py", line 290, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/cptsnuggles/run.py", line 282, in run
    _res = await asyncio.gather(*jobs1, return_exceptions=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 827, in gather
    fut = ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 680, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think, I'm missing something in my fundamental understanding here but I can't figure it out alone. Thank you for your replies!

Comment: asyncio wants to work with asynchronous types. You’d need to use `async def` with `main_func` and `backup_func` for them to work with `asyncio.gather`. But if neither of them await anything (like in your examples), asyncio will provide you no benefit and you’d be better off using concurrent.futures.

Comment: Gosh, absolutely right. I think the main point why my actual code isn't working is the fact that the `backup_func`, which is actually an external function from an imported library, is not an `async def`. I didnt think about that, thanks for opening my eyes on this one!

Comment: Posting the solution would be helpful.